# Оптимизация создания базы

Tags: node.js

Пришёл за советом.
Использую библеотеку sequelize.
Была потеряна SQL, проект большой а именно база столбцы т.д
Возможно как то не руками создавать столбы т.д (так как много времени займёт и везде разные значения)

Comment: Что-то не совсем понятно что вы хотите. Правильно понимаю, что у вас есть модели в коде и вам надо с нуля развернуть структуру базы со всеми схемами?

Comment: @PZBird да, с нуля развернуть структуру базы